# Complexity of foreach() in C# . NET

Tags: c#, .net, c, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Friends, I am using C# . NET where I need to read 8 millions line from a file and compute on it. When I do same operation in C language, it takes time but not to much while in C# it goes to very very high time complexity in the loop I mentioned below. Is it like foreach() is having high complexity? What could be the reason of difference between both?

```
foreach(string currLine in file.lines)
{
    Tuple tpl = new Tuple(currLine,file.keyLength);
    Console.WriteLine(file.lines.IndexOf(currLine));

    if(tpl.isWeakKey(B)==true)
    {
        int nextKey=tpl.findNextKey(B);

        if (differentKeys.ContainsKey(nextKey))
        {
            differentKeys[nextKey] = differentKeys[nextKey]+1;
        }
        else
        {
            differentKeys[nextKey] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `differentKeys` is a hashtable, then it is `O(n)` plus `tpl.findNextKey()` which you have not shown...

Comment: What is `file.lines`, exactly? Bear in mind that you're writing to the console in that loop - I'd expect that to be *much, much* more expensive than the `foreach` part. (And you're using `IndexOf` in there too, which will be O(n) on each iteration.) Have you tried removing the `Console.WriteLine` statement entirely?

Comment: Are you really writing 8Mio lines to the console?

Comment: I guess `Console.WriteLine` for 8 million lines is the bottleneck. You could use [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx) to read large files in _views_.

Comment: As @TaW noticed, I/O is the bottleneck

Comment: I agree with the others above. Don't print to the console!

Comment: Did you try just incrementing a counter in the foreach ? you would probably realize doing this that the complexity is not in foreach, but  in several other lines of your code.

Comment: also try to replace  if (differentKeys.ContainsKey(nextKey) ) with differentKeys.TryGetValue()

Comment: Guys, but in Linux C also I was printing probably than how there it was working easily? And Tim can you please elaborate more on MemoryMappedFile?

Comment: Any chance of seeing the C version to see if they are even equivalent? It is very easy to write good code in one language and port it to very poor code in another. That said, most of what people have said so far should produce some performance improvements for you.

Comment: differentKeys are Dictionary. FindKey() is having O(1) complexity

Comment: Don't call `IndexOf` inside the loop. Calculate the index (as you probably did in C), or use LINQ's `Select` method, which gives you the index

Answer (score 2):

You call to `IndexOf` method inside the loop, to get the current index. This method has a O(n) complexity, which means the whole loop is O(n²) complexity.

If instead you'll just use an index, and increment it manually, you'll get something more similar to the C code.

Another way, which be more C#ish (as I see it) is use LINQ to give you the index:

```
foreach(string currLine in file.lines.Select((Text, Index) => new { Text, Index)))
{
    Tuple tpl = new Tuple(currLine.Text,file.keyLength);
    Console.WriteLine(currLine.Index);

    // ** No need to compare with boolean. if, already expect a boolean.
    if(tpl.isWeakKey(B))
    {
        int nextKey=tpl.findNextKey(B);

        if (differentKeys.ContainsKey(nextKey))
        {
            differentKeys[nextKey] = differentKeys[nextKey]+1;
        }
        else
        {
            differentKeys[nextKey] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```